# Which of these cryptocurrency charts communicates percentage gain or loss in the most clear manner?

Tags: usability, tables, data-tables, charts, cryptocurrency

Cryptocurrency websites have been popping left and right for some time now and it seems they are already trying to establish patterns around their tools. One of the things most websites assume is that a person may be interested in seeing price change of a coin in terms of percentage in the last 1 hour, 24 hours or 7 days. Different websites follow different patterns and I am trying to validate the right methodology for representing this data. Here comes a bunch of charts and I would like to know which one is usable, useful and will probably be used

**1 Coinmarketcap**

[image]

- [Coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/) is the largest website in terms of traffic and it follows a rather simple pattern
- Last 7 days of price change with red color to highlight negative changes and green color to highlight positive changes
- They use a yellow color line chart which is non-interactive (doesn't reveal any data when you hover over the chart) as it seems to be a static image
- They have chosen a 7d price change to represent. Not sure why they won't take the last 24 hours. I am assuming most people just want to know the percentage by which an asset has changed in 24 hours

**2 Coincheckup**

[image]

- Unlike the coinmarketcap chart, the one at [coincheckup](https://coinlib.io/) has interactivity built into it. If you were to say hover over the chart, you would see price values
- They have used red and green colors which at first sight is not so obvious but then you compare the numbers in their 7d price column with the color of their chart, it becomes obvious that positive gainers in the 7d chart are green whereas the others are red. **This isn't obvious readily I think**
- They have also taken a 7d price change. At this point, I am guessing this should be the default for my tool given how much traffic both these sites generate

**3 Coingecko**

[image]

[Coingecko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjEDg.png) is very similar to coinmarketcap

**4 Coinlib**

[image]

- [Coinlib](https://coinlib.io/) is completely different than the rest of the crowd as I still haven't been able to figure out what its chart means.
- Guess that is a strong indicator of bad UX

**5 Coincall**

[image]

- No interactivity but [coincall](https://coincall.io/) still seems to have a very minimal smooth price graph compared to the rest. Not sure why

**6 Coincodex**

[image]

- [Coincodex](https://coincodex.com/) is doing things differently than the rest
- Their chart is non interactive but it seems to be colored or filled as you would call it
- They have also taken the 24 hour period as default which I think would go against the majority of the guys above
- The chart in itself probably doenst convey gains or losses but the red or green colored numbers to its left surely does

My question

- Which of these convey the information in a friendly manner
- How do I know the usability of these charts
- Are they really necessary? Sure coinmarketcap has them so probably will have to add them but do they make sense outside the context of follow the players
- I dont want to overload a plethora of colors on the user or complex shapes but at the same time, it has to be minimal and convey the information in the simplest way possible

Thank you for reading

Comment: I like blockchain/crypto related questions on UXSE, it is a good way to explore new areas in UX design and development. Are you working on an app yourself since you have been asking a few questions lately? :)

Comment: @MichaelLai yup will be launching a tool soon that is geared to be very different from the rest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they all don't seem to do is to provide the user with the option to choose the displayed time frame to something else.

For example 7 days could be the default, but why not give the user the option to change it to 30 days or overall right then and there?

As often there is no overall ideal solution but rather an ideal solution for your target audience.

If your audience comes mostly from wall street brokers then the visualization of Coinlib might be the most ideal for them, while Coinmarketcap might use the most ideal solution for people with little to no background in currency trading, therefor rather minimalistic and simple, but also lacking deeper information.

**Find out who your target audience is, how tech savvy they are and what there goals and needs are, since you were able to wright out this post i am sure you will find a way to create the ideal solution for your audience as soon as you can answer the stuff above.**

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Pectoralis Major. I would like to point out a different issue with these charts, though. Imagine you have a chart like this over 24 hrs:

[image]

Now, since the crypto markets don't have a daily close like regular markets do, the percentage gain/loss is not calculated over yesterday's close (which would tell you how much you gained/lossed compared to yesterday), but is comparing the value against the value yesterday at the same time. This means that if the price stayed at 80, the loss at 00:00 would be -20% (80/100 - 1), the loss at 01:00 would be -16.67% (80/96 - 1) and the loss at 12:00 would be 0% (80/80 - 1). This might falsely lead to a conclusion that the stock is rising, when it's, in fact, stable.